# I'm getting a Failed to restore the NuGet packages with react native run-windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-native, nuget, native

I'm trying to run the `react-native run-windows` command in my terminal but every time I run it I get this error message.

```
 √ Found NuGet Binary
 × Failed to restore the NuGet packages: Error: MSBuild tools not found. Make sure all required components have been installed (e.g. v141 support)
```

Has anyone gotten this problem before? And if so do you know the root cause of this?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Let me know if you found some workaround for it

Answer (score 1):

In your visual studio installer you need to Enable the optional C++ (v141) Universal Windows Platform tools

from this link [here](http://Enable%20the%20optional%20C++%20(v141)%20Universal%20Windows%20Platform%20tools)

In visual studio 2019 it is hidden but in Installation details -> Universal Windows Platform development -> C++ (v141) Universal Windows Platform tools (Here)

It is the first time that I use react native for Windows development.  I had this error because I forgot this step, so I uninstall everything and then reinstall it with this package and it worked.

Comment: I didn't re-install everything, just hit the `Start > Visual Installer` and clicked `Modify` from there I selected the Universal Windows Platform tools as mentioned above. Made sure to  check the box for the v141 support.